# dis-juncting ( or Break) the string based on a punctuation in python

Tags: python, regex, string, raw-input, punctuation

Is there any way to break string based on punctuation-word

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Asking user to Enter a line in specified format
myString=raw_input('Enter your String:\nFor Example:I am doctor break I stays in CA break   you can contact me on +000000\n')
# 'break' is punctuation word 
<my code which breaks the user input based on break word and returns output in different lists>
```

Expecting output like

`String1:I am doctor`

`String2:I stays in CA`

`String2:you can contact me on +000000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `regex` based solution, this would also take care of the trailing and leading whitespaces:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "I am doctor break I stays in CA break   you can contact me on +000000\n"
>>> re.split(r'\s+break\s+', text)
['I am doctor', 'I stays in CA', 'you can contact me on +000000\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method on strings as well, which returns a list of all tokens based on the split delimiter.

```
>>> a="test break testagain break again!"
>>> a.split(" break ")
['test ', ' testagain ', ' again!']
```

Comment: This would also split `"unbreakable"`, use `split(" break ")`.